# why before_update callback is fired on create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models, one Logo can have many Orders.

```
Class Logo
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :logo

Class Order
  belongs_to :logo, -> {includes :simulations}, autosave: true, inverse_of: :orders
```

Logo has a `before_update` callback that as far as I know Rails would be fired only on logo instance #update. Problem is that during Order#create my callback is being fired. Any ideas why?

Comment: Not exactly the same issue, but may be related to: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17289

Comment: Thanks, I've read about this issue, seems to be related to logic of the app described there.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an `Order`, the process is as follows:

1. Initialize `Order` record, setting appropriate attributes.
2. Persist the `Order` record to the database.
3. The `autosave` hook fires, calling a `save` on the relative records of the association, in this case, the `Logo` which said `Order` belongs to.
4. The corresponding `Logo` being saved causes the `before_update` callback to execute.

If you don't want this to happen, you can remove the `autosave: true` from the association to `:logo` on `Order`.  However, if there are other attributes about `Logo` that must change on creation of an `Order`, you will need to account for that in other code / callbacks within `Order`.

Comment: Seems like a good explanation what's happening. However, I am in doubt about one thing: all database operations related to Order#create are happening inside one transaction. Among them, first I see SQL `INSERT into logos`, then (triggered by another callback) `UPDATE logos SET`. Could it be the trigger causing firing the `before_update`?

Comment: If you're seeing `UPDATE logos ...` at all in your log files, yes, the `before_update` on `Logo` will be triggered.